# Tkinter button color flashing for no reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a refresh function to change the color of a button in tkinter, the problem is that this color must come from another function that returns a string and everytime I update everything flashes for a moment.

I've tried using StringVar() and only update the color without updating the whole layout but it would just get stuck in the loop and never display the layout. 
I tried also dumping all objets into a list and then changing the whole grid at once instead of one by one without much success.

The core of the code is :

```py
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
root.title("States")
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
grid=Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
Grid.rowconfigure(frame, 7, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(frame, 0, weight=1)

def loop_1():
        for x in range(4):
            for y in range(3):
                btnxy(x,y,frame)
        for x in range(4):
            Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)
        for y in range(3):
            Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)
        root.after(1000,loop_1)
loop_1()
```

where btnxy creates a button and places it in a grid

```py
def btnxy(x,y,frame):
    index=4*y+x+1
    if index>8:
        message="Relay "+str(index-8)
        btn = Button(frame,text=message, command=lambda p=(index-8): Relay(index-8), bg="blue", relief="groove", height=10, width=30)
    else:
        message="Entrée "+str(index)
        color=check_color(index)
        btn = Button(frame,text=message, command="", bg=color, relief="groove", height=10, width=30)
    btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W
```

And check_color is a function that returns a string with either "red" or "green"

To my understandig this should not take much processing power and thus update easly but it flashes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to tinker a bit with your code, but I honestly could not get it to work and do not understand the logic behind it. There are multiple points that are not ok:

1) global imports are bad. Do not use `from tkinter import *`. Instead use `import tkinter as tk`. This improves readability, makes things explicit and has many other benefits (You can easily find out more on Google on this)

2)You use the function `loop1` to place the buttons in the desired frame. That's all well and good, but you don't pass the frame as an argument, and the same holds for `root`. If you indeed modify your code to account for this, you will see that the flashing disappears, though you will have problems with `root.after` due to the lack of arguments.

The solution here is to change the structure of the app so that the buttons and the root are easily accessible and available. A way to get you started can be this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import shuffle


def get_random_colors():
    colors = ["red" for i in range(4)] + ["blue" for i in range(4)] + ["green" for i in range(4)]
    shuffle(colors)
    return colors


class MyGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.frame = tk.Frame()
        self.frame.pack()

        self.n_rows = 3
        self.n_cols = 4

        self.bt_list = []

        for x in range(self.n_rows):
            for y in range(self.n_cols):
                self.bt_list.append(tk.Button(self.frame, text="Button {}.{}".format(x, y)))
                self.bt_list[-1].grid(row=x, column=y)

    def change_colors(self):
        colors = get_random_colors()
        for index, button in enumerate(self.bt_list):
            button.configure(bg=colors[index])
        self.after(5000, self.change_colors)

root = MyGUI()
root.after(5000, root.change_colors)
root.mainloop()
```

First of all, the main frame is now an attribute of the class, so it suffices to just call `self.frame` whenever I need it in the class, as long as self was passed to the function.
Then I decided to store the buttons in a list, so that I can always access them in my class through `self`. This is useful because in the change_colors function I can just loop through the list and change the button through `.configure(bg=<color here>)`.
Last point is the `.after`. I call it once outside the the class constructor just after I define `root`, and then inside the `change_colors` function using `self`.
The final code should change the colors of the button randomly every 5 seconds.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is mucho easier than what I was doing. Thank you!